# MSBuild treating Content files differently in different environments

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, jenkins

I have a project with a structure like this:

```
> Project
>     App 
>         Config
>             File1.json
>             File2.json
```

File1.json and File2.json are marked as Content, copy if newer.

When I build/publish using Visual Studio, the output is:

```
> bin
>     App
>         Config
>             File1.json
>             File2.json
```

When the project is built from the command line, the output is

```
> bin
>     File1.json
>     File2.json
```

Any idea why this would be?  I need to be able to reference these files in a known location, so this is something of a problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could configure your output path in Properties

> Right click Project -> Properties -> Build -> Output Path

Or you could manually edit it in the `.csproj` file

```
<OutputPath>myOutputLocation\myBin\</OutputPath>
```

Comment: Thanks - the output path is already set to bin\ - and in both cases, the files are in fact output to the bin, just that in one case, the path is retained and in the other, it is stripped out.

Comment: @sydneyos: Is there a difference in the configuration used i.e `Debug` or `Release`.
Each will have its own `OutputPath`

Comment: @@jacob alysious, in both cases, the configuration was set to Debug

Comment: @sydneyos: On the command line, you should be able to specify the Output path also as arguments.. Guess this should override the defaults..